# Ansible check hosts file

Tags: ansible, automated-tests, ansible-inventory

Ansible: 2.9

I search a command or option how to check consistency between my "hosts" inventory file vs. group_vars tree fs.

I explain:

- My Host file:

```
[all]
N01
N02
S01
S02

[zone1]
N01
N02

[zone2]
S01
S02

[zone3]
Z01
Z02
```

- Group_vars tree FS:

```
PlayBook_dir
\__group_vars:
   - zone1.yml
   - zone2.yml
```

- Desired, make a Test with this check:

*When I launch my Playbook he show a similar of "Error No zone3 in group_var dir tree".*

You know for this or other tests?

Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a play on localhost that checks for the existence of the `group_vars` files using the [stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/stat_module.html). The results of this can be checked with [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html).

```yaml
    # First stat the path for file existence by looping over inventory groups
    - stat:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/{{ item.key }}.yml"
      loop: "{{ groups | dict2items }}"
      register: gvars

    # Loop over the registered variable and fail assertion if path doesn't exist
    - assert:
        that:
        - item.stat.exists
        fail_msg: "{{ item.invocation.module_args.path }} does not exist"
      when:
        - item.item.key not in ["all", "ungrouped"]
      loop: "{{ gvars.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.key }}"
```